# proxy in Ext js return error SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Tags: php, linux, apache2

I'm new in Extjs. I have an test.js.php page that in a part of this, there is **Ext.data.Store** :

```
this.store2 = new Ext.data.Store({
    fields : ["Pid","bid"],
    proxy : {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url:  '../d/sample.data.php?task=GetUser',
        reader: {
            root: 'rows',
            totalProperty: 'totalCount'
        }
    }
});
```

and in **../d/sample.data.php** page I have this in summery:

```
$task = isset($_POST ["task"]);
if($task == "GetUser")
   GetUser();


function GetUser() {

  $dt = array();
  $dt = array_merge($dt, Pdo::runquery("select PID , bid from mytable where PID  = ? ", array($_SESSION['PID'])));

  echo dataReader::getJsonData($dt, count($dt), $_GET["callback"]);
  die();
}
```

these codes are running well in site but not in my virtualHost.when I run in localhost , get this message in console :
**SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'** and it refere to sample.data.php:1

*I try below for all files in /var/www/myVirtualHostName:*

```
chmod 777 -R ./*
```

ps:
I'm using ubuntu 20.04 , virtual host , php5.6 and apache2

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need jsonp proxy? In this case it is better to use standard AJAX proxy with JSON reader. Something like:

```
this.store2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
fields : ["Pid","bid"],
proxy : {
    type: 'ajax',
    url:  '../d/sample.data.php?task=GetUser',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'rows',
        totalProperty: 'totalCount'
    }
}
});
```

JsonP is used for cross domain requests.